# Trouble adding authentication with React and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having issues adding authentication to an app I have been working on.
Everything works fine with firebase as-is without the auth, until I start adding these new lines, which are basically just:

```
export const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
export const auth = firebase.auth();

import firebase, { auth, provider } from './firebase.js';
```

I have a file for my config (config.js), which just contains an export for DB_CONFIG (with all my correct info). Here's where I'm running into issues. The tutorial I'm following has firebase imported and initialized in the config file, while I am doing so in my App.js file. I've been trying different things for a couple hours and nothing is working for me. If I import firebase into my config and initializeApp there, it breaks my App.js. Here's a gist of [my code vs. what I'm trying to follow.](https://gist.github.com/scottmiller2/99b3b1893ed474592667b8ea2189bc87)

Is there an easy way to get the auth and provider set up and imported into my App.js file without changing too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code I made some changes to it, maybe this approach help?

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import { DB_CONFIG } from './Config/config';

// Configure firebase and it will be available globally.
firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG)

// Once initialized you just need to create the provider and auth
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
const auth = firebase.auth();

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    // And just call firebase.database() to access database functionality.
    // You don't even need to assign it to a local variable as you can access 
    // it anywhere in your code just by importing firebase
    // and calling firebase.database() and also firebase.auth()
    this.databaseRef = firebase.database().ref().child('players');
  }
}
```

PS: I would delete your gist because, even though you changed the config file, your configuration info is still available in the gist revisions...

Comment: That seems to be working well, thanks for that! And thanks for alerting me of the Gist.